# Marketing Cloud Synchronization data Sources

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, data-synchronization

Do you know how long it would take to synchronise data from sfdc to sfmc if there around are 1.5m contact records being synchronised?

Thanks

Comment: it will take minimum is 15 min for sync data from sfdc to sfmc  and maximum is 1 hour that is you can choose option

Answer (score 0):

It will also depend on how many contact record fields and how much data in such fields that you wish to sync.

From experience, I synced similar volume of records and ~25 fields which took about 10 - 15 mins.

At the first time sync this is the master sync as from there on it becomes a delta sync of contact records which have changed